# SQLite Go through each column in Row

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a sqlite statement that provides me with a selected single row and 20 columns.

Up to now I've been using this while loop:

```
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, an_incrementing_int)];
    ...
    }
```

However the problem with this is as there is only one row it will naturally only return the 1st column.

So is there something like `while.. == SQLITE_COLUMN` ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `an_incrementing_int` is for???

Comment: I've got that in but as the while loop will only run through once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get number of column a query returns, use [`sqlite3_column_count`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_count.html).

Function to return column data, [`sqlite3_column_...`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) all accept an 2nd argument which is `int` column index.

```
NSString coldata;
int i;
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    for (i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(statement); ++i) {
        coldata= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];
    }
}
```

Note also: take care using data pointer to column values!

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as
>   described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or
>   sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings
>   and BLOBs is freed automatically. Do not pass the pointers returned
>   from sqlite3_column_blob(), sqlite3_column_text(), etc. into
>   sqlite3_free().